# My pageAction icon remains inactive in Chrome webextension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json

I am writing a webextension for Chrome and Firefox that uses the Page Action model.  In the `manifest.json` I provide match rules for the URL so that it only shows on a specific URL.  This works fine in Firefox, but the icon stays inactive all the time in Chrome. Here's my Chrome `manifest.json`, which is the same as the Firefox one but without the firefox specific `aplications` property.  The url of the webpage when loaded is exactly the same in Chrome as in Firefox.

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,

"name": "MyExtension",
"version": "0.1.1",
"description": "A description",
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
],
"page_action": {
    "default_title": "MyExtension",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/icon16.png",
        "32": "images/icon32.png",
        "48": "images/icon48.png",
        "128": "images/icon128.png"
      },
    "show_matches": ["https://example.com/@*"],
    "hide_matches": ["https://example.com/@*/*"]
}
```

}

Comment: See the documentation and demo extensions. There's no such keys as show_matches and hide_matches in Chrome. You need to use chrome.declarativeContent or chrome.webNavigation + chrome.pageAction.show().

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm.  I've changed to using `.declarativeContent` and I've got it working now.  Cheers.